# PHP no route found for POST with FOSRestBundle

Tags: php, rest, symfony, post, fosrestbundle

I am working on a project were i have to use javascript to detect screen resolution, viewport...

I am using Symfony 2.8, and i created a REST API for posting(client side with ajax) screen setings to the server side (and put it in a Doctrine entities).

I am testing the API with:

```
curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"screen":[{"id": 1,"resolution": "1920x1080", "viewport": "60x60", "device_ar": "1.5", "px_ratio": "1.00", "zoom": "8%"}]}' myurl/api/screen
```

and i have a wonderfull No route found for POST.

Here is my routing.yml:

```
screen:
type:   rest
prefix: /api
resource:   MyBrowserBundle\Controller\ScreenController
methods: [POST]
```

and my screen controller:

```
class ScreenController extends FOSRestController
{

/**
*   @var $resolution, $viewport, $device_ar, $px_ratio, $zoom
*   @Post()
*/
public function postScreenAction($resolution, $viewport, $device_ar, $px_ratio, $zoom)
{

    $userpost_screen = new Screen();

    $userpost_screen->setResolution($resolution);
    $userpost_screen->setViewport($viewport);
    $userpost_screen->setDeviceAr($device_ar);
    $userpost_screen->setPxRatio($px_ratio);
    $userpost_screen->setZoom($zoom);

    $em = $this->getDoctrine->getManager();
    $em->persist($userpost_screen);
    $em->flush();
}

}
```

And my config for fosrestbundle:

```
fos_rest:
param_fetcher_listener: true
body_listener: true
format_listener: true
view:
    view_response_listener: 'force'
    formats:
        xml: true
        json : true
    templating_formats:
        html: true
    force_redirects:
        html: true
    failed_validation: HTTP_BAD_REQUEST
    default_engine: twig
routing_loader:
    default_format: json
```

I'm working on this since this morning and i still can't find what happend, a little help can be usefull :)

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so i changed my controller to this:

```
public function postScreenAction(Request $request)
{

   $userpost_screen = new Screen();
   $em              = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
   $params          = array();
   $content         = $this->get("request")->getContent();
   if (!empty($content)) {
       $params = json_decode($content, true);
   }

    $userpost_screen->setResolution($params["screen"]["resolution"]);
    $userpost_screen->setViewport($params["screen"]["viewport"]);
    $userpost_screen->setDeviceAr($params["screen"]["device_ar"]);
    $userpost_screen->setPxRatio($params["screen"]["px_ratio"]);
    $userpost_screen->setZoom($params["screen"]["zoom"]);


    $em->persist($userpost_screen);
    $em->flush();
}
```

testing with :

```
curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"screen":{"resolution": "1920x1080", "viewport": "60x60", "device_ar": "1.5", "px_ratio": "1.00", "zoom": "8%"}}' dev/~bgonckel/web/symfony/MyBrowser/web/app_dev.php/api/screen
```

And it work fine :)